# I can't see the image in html preview (2021)

Tags: html

I can't see the image in browser preview of html, i did it like  Image o=is saved as mac.png, but it isn't showing, but when i write <img src="file:///Users/MYNAME/desktop/mac.png", it shows. Pls help

Comment: check if you are running the app by the server or just opening an HTML file in a browser. if running by the server, file location should be an absolute path, or else relative path works

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand.